# Select files using file browser and store the path in a python script

Tags: python, csv, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to use a file browser to load a few .csv(let's call them csv1) files and run them in my python script. As a result it will copy some columns from csv1 and generate a new .csv file (csv2). I have written the codes for the file browser, and also the script to generate the csv2 file. However, I cannot find a way to use the file browser to select the csv1 and then input it in my script to create the csv2 file.

If anyone knows the solution, please help to comment. Appreciated a lot!!

The following is my codes so far:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import os, sys
import subprocess

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, 400, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Multiple Browse')     

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Browse', self)
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.clicked.connect(self.SingleBrowse)
        btn.move(150, 100)     

        self.show()

    def SingleBrowse(self):
        filePaths = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, 
                                                   'Multiple File',
                                                   "Desktop",
                                                  '*.csv')

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


## Below codes are initially from a separate script, but I just combine them 
## together in one. Because I think maybe I could call the class function 
## "Wideget" somewhere below for using the file browser to select the files?

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df1 = pd.read_csv('csv0.csv') 
df2 = pd.read_csv('csv1.csv')

df3 = df1.loc[:, ['a_column', 'b_column']] 

df3[""] = "" 

df4 = df2.loc[:, ['c_column','d_column' , 'e_column']]

new = pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=1)

new.index = new.index + 1

new.to_csv('csv2.csv')
```

Comment: Is that one module? Or is the code from `import pandas as pd` a separate module? It seems odd, and possibly not what you want, to have module-level code mixed with PyQt classes.

Comment: Do you want to select a file or several?

Comment: Also note that by convention class *methods* start with lower case, so `SingleBrowse` should be `singleBrowse` or - even more Pythonic - `single_browse`. It'll still work either way, though.

Comment: I understand that you want to select csv0.csv and csv1.csv through the browser file. I am right?

Comment: @JoeP It is actually from 2 separate modules(scripts) but I just combine them together. Because I thought once I created the button with the class "Widget", I could call it somewhere at the codes after "import pandas as pd" ?  thx:)

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to select 2 files in total, but one file at a time. And yes I want to select csv0.csv and csv1.csv through the browser! Is there any way to do that?   thx:)

Comment: see my answer :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the path of 2 files one by one you have to use getOpenFileName, in addition I understand that they must be different file so we verify that it has not been previously selected

```
def initUI(self):
    # ...
    self.csv = []

def SingleBrowse(self):
        if len(self.csv) < 2:
            filePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 
                                                   '',
                                                   "Desktop",
                                                  '*.csv')

            if filePath != "" and not filePath in self.csv:
                self.csv.append(filePath)
        print(self.csv)
```

Comment: thanks!! :p  I tried this and called the main() but it still couldn't load the right paths tho... I will post my modified script below and pls let me know where I did wrong if possible. Appreciated!!

Comment: Below the main is a code, that is inside the same script or in another one?

Comment: thanks a lot!! Man you're awesome and it worked perfectly! :)